# Image doesn't fill external screen

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I'm building a MonoTouch app that has UI on the iOS device screen and images on a second screen via HDMI. When displaying an image within a UIImageView the image doesn't fill the second screen. Below is the code to setup and display the image on the external screen. The UIScreen.Screens[1] width and height give me the correct values 1920/1080. I get an 1 inch border on top/bottom and 1.5 inch on the left/right when I display the image. Using MPMoviePlayerController with similar external screen setup fills the screen.

```
    public void SetImageExternal(string imageFile)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageFile) == false)
        {
            UIScreen externalScreen;
            UIWindow externalWindow;
            UIView externalView;
            UIImageView externalImageView;
            SizeF externalScreenSize;

            if(UIScreen.Screens.Length > 1)
            {

                if(externalWindow != null)
                    externalWindow.Dispose();
                externalWindow = null;

                externalScreenSize = new SizeF();
                externalScreenSize.Width = 0;
                externalScreenSize.Height = 0;
                UIScreenMode maxScreenMode = null;
                externalScreen = UIScreen.Screens[1];

                // Use the screen with the largest width
                for(int i = 0; i < externalScreen.AvailableModes.Length; i++)
                {       
                    UIScreenMode current = UIScreen.Screens[1].AvailableModes[i];
                    if(current.Size.Width > externalScreenSize.Width)
                    {
                        externalScreenSize = current.Size;
                        maxScreenMode = current;
                    }
                }

                externalScreen.CurrentMode = maxScreenMode;

                externalWindow = new UIWindow(new RectangleF(0, 0, externalScreenSize.Width, externalScreenSize.Height));
                externalWindow.RootViewController = new UIViewController(); // create dummy root view controller
                externalWindow.UserInteractionEnabled = false;

                externalImageView = new UIImageView(externalWindow.Frame);          
                externalImageView.Image = UIImage.FromBundle(imageFile);
                externalImageView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill;

                externalView = new UIView(externalWindow.Frame);
                externalView.AddSubview(externalImageView);

                foreach(UIView view in externalWindow.Subviews)
                    view.RemoveFromSuperview();
                externalWindow.AddSubview(externalView);
                externalWindow.MakeKeyAndVisible();
                externalWindow.Hidden = false;
                externalWindow.Screen = externalScreen;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the ContentMode deteremines how a prerendered version of the contents are scaled.

But the UIImageView determines how the image is scaled based on the parameters of UIImage's LeftCapWidth and TopCapHeight, only if those are not set, the ContentMode is used.